# Is it possible to debug another program in a GDB session without first quitting?

Tags: debugging, gdb, mingw, gnu

> Is it possible to debug another program in a GDB session without first quitting?

After having set up things like `set disassembly-flavor intel` and having debugged my first `program1`, I want to debug another `program2` without quitting the GDB session.

The  reason is, that I don't want to enter all of the commands, like the one above.

Usually, I first quit the original GDB session and debug `program2` using `gdb program2`, but there must be something smarter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `kill` the currently running inferior, then use `file` to select a new program to debug, then `run` it.

If you find yourself typing the same commands a lot, put them in your `~/.gdbinit`.  You can also enable history-saving so they will be in the command history when you restart gdb.

Comment: Thank you, I think it is weird that the "file" command is not listed in my cheat sheet and writing "gdb --help" doesn't display it either.

Comment: `gdb --help` just shows the command-line argument help.  For help on all the gdb commands, try `help` at the gdb prompt.  You can also use `apropos` to search the help text.